# Prove that $\Pr[X>0]\ge\cfrac{{\left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)}^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$

Tags: probability, inequality

I have found a [slide](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Ekabanets/881/scribe_notes/lec14.pdf) stating that for any random variable $X$, $\Pr[X>0]\ge\cfrac{{\left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)}^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$.

I have no clue on proving this inequality. I've considered the Markov's inequality, but it doesn't seem to entail $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$. I've also considered the case that $X$ is a continuous random variable, when the inequality is equivalent to

$$\newcommand{\d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\d x\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2f(x)\d x\ge{\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)\d x\right]}^2$$

This seems to resemble the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but the lower bound of the first integral is $0$ rather than $-\infty$ so it still seems not to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The proof is in the previous lecture notes: https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/881/scribe_notes/lec13.pdf

Comment: For a strictly negative random variable, this inequality is always false. The random variable discussed in your slide appears to be strictly positive.

Comment: (Or at least nonnegative almost surely.)

Comment: Once we assume $X$ is nonnegative, what we get is exactly the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.